# PHP MYSQL connection with query inside IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, database-connection

SOLVED:

There is a conlict with my declaring of variables. It turns out i declare a $password in my connect_database, but also in my account script meaning the $password is always set and therefore always skips pas the if's to the end...and since this is work in progress it's the same simple password as my account login...

ORIGINAL:

I have a problem with queries inside if statements in PHP. I'm doing an account update script.

I require the connection to the database at the top and then depending on the result from the POST, I do diffrent queries in some if statements.

If it runs passed all IF statements it runs a query at the end.

If it's caught by any of the if's, a query is made and I want the script to redirect with a message code and terminate the code with an exit.

The problem is the script will not exit after an if execution is made. It does the query but it runs all the way to the end - no redirect and exit...

I found a workaround which requires the database to be required inside the if statements and then again at the bottom instead of only at the top, but my initial idea was to just include it at the top and use the connection in the if statement and again at the bottom.

Can anyone explain why one works and the other doesn't?
It's not a big deal. I just don't understand why...

Thanks a lot

This doesnt work (**Require database outside of the IF statement**):

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
    header("location: ../../../login/login_form.php");
    exit;
}

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

//Display if user and email is blank - try again---------------
if($user==NULL || $email==NULL){
    header('location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=1');
    exit;
}

require_once('../../connect_database.php');

//Check if password is blank - meaning only updating user and email -----
if ($password==NULL){

    $query = "UPDATE user SET user='$user', email='$email' WHERE id=".$id;
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    header('location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=0');
    mysql_close();
    exit;
}

//Display if password less than 8 characers----------------
if(strlen($password)<8 && $password!=NULL){
    header('location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=2');
            mysql_close();
    exit;
}

//Run this if everything is to be changed incl. password-------

$query = "UPDATE user SET user='$user', password=md5('$password'), email='$email' WHERE id=".$id;
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

header('location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=0');

?>
```

This works (**Require database inside of the IF statement and then again at the bottom**):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
    header("location: ../../../login/login_form.php");
    exit;
}

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

//Display if user and email is blank - try again---------
if($user==NULL || $email==NULL){
    header('location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=1');
    exit;
}

//Check if password is blank - meaning only updating user and email ----
if ($password==NULL){

    require_once('../../connect_database.php');

    $query = "UPDATE user SET user='$user', email='$email' WHERE id=".$id;
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    header('location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=0');
    mysql_close();
    exit;
}

//Display if password less than 8 characers------------------
if(strlen($password)<8 && $password!=NULL){
    header('location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=2');
    exit;
}

//Run this if everything is to be changed incl. password----------
require_once('../../connect_database.php');

$query = "UPDATE user SET user='$user', password=md5('$password'), email='$email' WHERE id=".$id;
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

header('location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=0');

?>
```

Comment: Is your page set to display errors? `if ($password==NULL){` is also sending the user to the same location as the bottom of the page. Set a couple breaking points inside your if's like `echo 'inside if 1'; exit;` so see where it's getting caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is the script will not exit after an if execution is made.

you are wrong. `exit` operator is plain and simple and **always** work.
How do you know the query was executed? Any debug output you've got?

Thre are many issues with your code but at least make it less repetitive and moire consistent

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) { 
  header("location: ../../../login/login_form.php"); 
  exit; 
} 

$user     = $_POST['user']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$email    = $_POST['email']; 
$id       = $_SESSION['user_id']; 

//Display if user and email is blank - try again--------------- 
if (!$user || !$email) { 
  $message=1;
} 
//Display if password less than 8 characers---------------- 
elseif ($password && strlen($password)<8){ 
  $message=2;
} else {
  require_once('../../connect_database.php'); 
  $user  = mysql_real_escape_string($user); 
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email); 

  if ($password) { 
      $password = "password='".md5($password)."',";
  }
  $query = "UPDATE user SET user='$user',$password email='$email' WHERE id=".$id;
  mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
  $message  = 0;
}
header("location: ../../../index.php?show=account&message=$message");
```

Also note

- you cannot use mysql_real_escape_string before connect
- using relative paths (all those dots) considered bad practice, especially with location

Comment: Hi Col. Shrapnel. I know what the problem is. There is a conflict in my declaring of variables. In the connect_database i declare a $password but also in the script therefore it always skips the if's with the password checks...I've been thinking about this all weekend. I only just realized it....But thank you all for your suggestions!

Comment: Could you tell me what? I'm new at this.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel could you point me in the directions of what is wrong with my code I would like to learn...thanks

Comment: Hey, Col. Shrapnel. Thank you. This helps me so much! Thanks with the mysql_real_escape. Of course that makes sense. What would be better regarding the relative paths? dirname(dirname(__file__)) and so on?

Comment: @Woozle dirname won't help you for the location. location takes URL, not file. so, just make it an absolute path from the site url.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that location is case sensitive. Try changing it to

```
header("Location:../../../index.php?show=account&message=0");
```

Comment: It isn't case sensitive. I've seen all lower-case used many times before.

Comment: Thanks Eagle. That doesn't seem to be the problem. I just changed them and it's still the same.

Answer (score -1):

Ok here is what i suggest :
Replace all `exit` with `die()`
And if that doesn't work try replacing all the Location headers with this :

```
<script>
window.location='/path/to/your/redirection';
</script>
```

Let me know if that helps in any way :)

Comment: No good with the die instead of exit. I do this on all other pages and have no preoblem with exiting and redirecting. Only this where the mysql connection is used inside the if...

Comment: The first if statement works. The one if the user and email is blank but everything below the require connection is not working...

Comment: i was checking if somehow it was the exit that was acting suspiciously because sometimes it happens
in that case, try changing the IF, to `if(empty($password))`

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel : I wish you would give straight answers